# Concentric circles in inversive-geometry

Tags: inversive-geometry

Is it possible to obtain two concentric generalised circles(parallel straight lines) through inversion of two circles w.r.t a third circle?

Comment: If the center of the inversion does not belong to any of the given lines, the image of such lines will be circles through the inversion center, i.e. two intersecting circles. On the other hand, if the inversion center lies on one of the two initial lines, the image of a line is still a line. So **no**.

Comment: However, given two circles one inside the other, you may find an inversion that maps them into two concentric circles: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitingPoint.html

Comment: Does the inversion of two circles (one within the other) which are passing through the center of inversion (of a larger inverting circle) give rise to two concentric circles ?

Comment: How can two disjoint circles pass through the same point?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ParallelInvrsns]

Some parallel line segments  are shown reflected about a unit circle centered at origin as mirror ( feature available in *Geogebra*). When parallel lines go to $ \infty,$ then their images inside the inversion circle tend to go to the origin, being tangent only at an infinite distance from the farthest points .. a feature of hyperbolic geometry. The images can never be concentric just as in both the Poincare's models ( semi-infinite plane or disk.)

EDIT 1:

[image: nvesnParllLines]

Inversions of a set of parallel lines bear same label in the figure above.

A set of parallel lines have  *co-tangential* circular inversions.

These inversions have either to be *co-tangential* or *con-centric* but *not both* at the same time !!

Comment: If we consider the inversion of circles to get parallel lines(generalised circles of infinite radius),is it possible to obtain parallel lines( generalised circles) that are concentric?

Comment: In the answer the inversion of lines was considered,please consider the inversion of circles that gives concentric circles of infinite radius.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am unable to understand the comment immediately above.In a partial answer to the one above it I can only say::::  Basically inversions are a  homothety or scaling in a similitude situation,  I shall reply in EDIT1 soon,... to the extent that  I can understand.. .

Comment: If we consider the parallel lines in EDIT 1 as generalised circles of infinite radius, then is it possible for them to be concentric?
Or do these generalised circles(straight lines) meet at infinity ,similar to the original circles that meet at the center of inversion ?
(Thanks for the answer)

Comment: Please see the question titled :parallel lines as generalised circles in inversive geometry? It is the same question as above but I included a figure to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 0):

can the two straight lines in the figure be concentric circles in any case ?
Or if we have two parallel lines is it possible that they are concentric generalised circles?

[image]

Comment: If we consider two generalised circles (parallel lines) ,which are obtained through the inversion of two circles touching each other only at the center of inversion,then is it possible for the lines to be concentric circles ?
Does the larger circles(lines) also touch each other at one point (like the smaller circles before inversion)?